# Android How do i stop TalkBack including footer row when reading list items count

Tags: android, listview, footer, talkback

I have a dialog containing a list of notes, and I want to make the user scroll to the end of the list to find the "OK" button to close the dialog.

The dialog contains a ListView and I add the button to the list using the footer row.

```
View footerView = ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).
                inflate(R.layout.list_footer_button, null, false);
listView.addFooterView(footerView);
```

When i turn on talk back and open this dialog, it reads the wrong count for the ListView as it is including the footer row. For example if my list has 3 items, talkback reads "Item 1 of 4".

ISSUE

How can i get talkBack to read the correct number of items ignoring the footer row?

OR

If i can't change this, how else do i create a dialog where the user has to scroll to the end of the list before seeing the button to dismiss the dialog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue by adding the button to the View for the last row rather than adding a footer.

My layout for each row contains a textView and a button, and the button is set to be "invisible".

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/notes_details"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <!-- other views here but removed for this post -->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/notes_text"
            style="@style/notes_text_style"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/notes_button"
        style="@style/notes_button"
        android:layout_below="@id/notes_details"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In the adapter for the list, I show/hide the button based on whether the row is the last row

```
 boolean isLastRow = iPosition == getCount()-1;
 okButton.setVisibility(isLastRow ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
```

**Accessibility changes needed**

There was additional work to make this all work for Accessibility purposes. If no changes were made to support accessibility, only the rows are navigatable. Therefore the last row will select the notes text and OK button as one selectable item and you would not be able to navigate to the button using a keyboard/trackerball.

Firstly you have to set the list so that items in a row are focusable

```
listView.setItemsCanFocus(true);
```

Secondly, in code in the adapter, i set the focusable/nextFocusXXX on the notes textView and button accordingly

```
// when in accessibility mode, we want to set the navigation order for
// the list item's text and the OK button
boolean isLastRow = iPosition == getCount()-1;
if (isAccessibilityEnabled) {
    notesTextView.setFocusable(true);
    okButton.setFocusable(true);
    rowView.setNextFocusForwardId(isLastRow ? R.id.notes_button: R.id.notes_text);
    rowView.setNextFocusDownId(isLastRow ? R.id.notes_button: R.id.notes_text);
    okButton.setNextFocusUpId(R.id.notes_text);
}
```

Comment: This helps in the cases where i can add the button to the last row. However in some cases I can not. I would like to be able to tell TalkBack to not include the footer when reading out the count. I find it odd that TalkBack includes the footer as headers and footers are not actual list items and i would expect TalkBack to read the number of items

Comment: Sadly this approach doesn't work with the NavigationDrawer where I have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had another usecase with this issue.

**Requirements**

I have a screen containing a list of items and I have a Floating Action Button (FAB) on the bottom right of the screen allowing the user to add items to the list. On the right hand side of each row is a button presenting options for that row item.

I need the FAB to not overlay the last row in the list, otherwise I am never able to click on the right hand button of the last row as it will be under the FAB.

**Solutions and their issues**

I tried several solutions. One was adding an extra count to the list items and when getting the view for this last row I return an empty view, the height of the FAB.  I also tried adding this empty padding row as the list footer.  In both cases TalkBack reads one too many for the number of items in the list.

I can not use the solution I have posted for this question for my list of notes. I need the FAB to always be in the bottom right hand side of the screen (not just after the last row) even if there are only 1 or 2 items in the list or over a screen-full of items.

**Working Solution**

Adding the last 4 attributes in the code below to my list definition in the xml layout seems to solve the issue. There are no additional items added to the list so TalkBack reads the list count correctly and the following ensures the FAB in the bottom left of the screen never overlaps the last row.

```
<!-- Instead of adding a footer row to stay clear of the FAB,
     add a padding to the listView and set clipToPadding to false
     android:overScrollFooter is set to transparent to avoid having a divider
     for the last item  so there is just white space below the last item -->

<ListView
    style="@style/my_list_style"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

    android:paddingBottom="82dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
    android:overScrollFooter="@android:color/transparent"/>
```